# Unable to connect to MySQL instance after installing

Tags: mysql

I'm setting up a MySQL database following [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx) tutorial. I installed it and successfully initialized an instance with a root password, but I am having trouble connecting to the instance via command line. When I click on the 'mysql' executable under bin, I get this message

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'hunter'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

and if I try to enter

```
> mysql -u root -p
```

in the terminal I get this message

```
-bash: mysql: Permission denied
```

It says in the instructions that I should be getting prompted to enter the password for the database, but for some reason it won't let me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full content of your console/shell so we can see what you entered at which point and what exact output was generated (by the mysql client or by your console/shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest first off to try a mysql workbench. You can download it at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ .

It seems that calling mysql from bash is causing issues for you. If you are using a *Nix environment, it could be a permissions issue and you need to set the correct permissions on the mysql binary. However, usually a correct installation should have already done that. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi

Secondly, you should use the username `root` . `hunter` is not default username.

From the mysql documentation:

> How to Reset the Root Password
> **If you have never assigned a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root**. However, this is insecure. For instructions on assigning a password, see Section 2.10.4, “Securing the Initial MySQL Account”.

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I will try to connect with the workbench - looks like it has an easier to understand interface. For future reference though, how do I change my username if I'm doing it from bash?

Comment: Open the bash shell and connect to the server as root user
`mysql -u root -h localhost -p`
Run command:
`ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';`
From: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-user-password/#:~:text=Open%20the%20bash%20shell%20and,'New%2DPassword%2DHere'%3B

Comment: I already connected on Workbench (super easy) but your first command still results in a permission denied message :/

Comment: How did you install mysql? did you extract it ? or install using apt-get or yum?

Comment: I just downloaded the disk image - I'm on MacOS btw